# Google Sheets Divide value if other column not empty

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula

I have a sheet with the following values in minutes to keep track of how long it takes for x task:

```
+---------+----------+----------+
|    A    |    B     |    C     |
+---------+----------+----------+
| Task    | Person 1 | Person 2 |
| Task #1 | 10       | 20       |
| Task #2 | 20       | 0        |
| Task #3 | 0        | 30       |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

I want to get total of hours for every task but if a task has time for Person 1 and Person 2, I want the average of the time taken for the task.

What I've had in mind previously is:

```
=(SUM(Tasks!$B$2:$B) + SUM(Tasks!$C$2:$C)) / 2
```

I thought this would work but then I realized it won't because some tasks are only handled by Person 1.

The total of the previous formula would give me `40`, but what I'm expecting as a value should be `65`, based on the following calculation:

```
(10 + 20) / 2 + 20 + 30
```

Comment: How is my question unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF((B2:B4>0)*(C2:C4>0),(B2:B4+C2:C4)/2,B2:B4+C2:C4))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B4+C2:C4)/((B2:B4>0)+(C2:C4>0)))
```

Comment: The only issue, with this is if both B and C are 0 in any of the rows, it will error.

Comment: @Scott Nice catch. So,  =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((B2:B4+C2:C4)/((B2:B4>0)+(C2:C4>0)),0))

Comment: That works but it needs to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  So just use SUM() and save typing 7 more letters.

Comment: no, in Excel, when putting in the IFERROR inside the SUMPRODUCT it requires the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter, and since it did I would change SUM for SUMPRODUCT to save some typing, but you are correct sheets does not have the limitation on IFERROR that Excel has.  I would edit your answer to include your new formula and just note that in Excel it requires the CSE, while Sheets does not.